# Complex Analysis: Cauchy Integral Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, solution-verification

I came across this problem.

> > Let $C$ denote the circle {|z| =2}, parametrized as a positively oriented simple closed curve. Evaluate $\int_c\frac{1}{z^2-1}dz$

I want to approach this problem using the Cauchy Integral Formula. Let $g(z) = \frac{1}{z^2-1}$. $g(z)$ is analytic everywhere on the closed curve except at $z = \pm1.$ We can manipulate g(z) via partial fraction decomposition.

\begin{eqnarray}
g(z) = \frac{1}{z^2-1}& = & \frac{1}{(z+1)(z-1)}\\
& = &  \frac{-1/2}{z+1} + \frac{1/2}{z-1}
\end{eqnarray}
Thus we can have the following set up.
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_C\frac{dz}{z^2-1} & = & -\frac{1}{2}\int_C\frac{1}{z+1}dz + \frac{1}{2}\int_C\frac{1}{z-1}dz\\
& = & -\frac{1}{2}2\pi if_1(-1) + \frac{1}{2}2\pi if_2(1)\\
& = & -\pi i + \pi i = 0\\
\end{eqnarray}

Did I approach this correctly?

Thank you for your time and thank you for any feedback you provide.

Answer (score 2):

The integral is indeed zero as you claim. This in fact can be seen easier since the integrand $g$ is an even function.

**EDIT:**

Allow me to expand on my comment. Suppose $f(z)$ is even, and $C$ is a circle centered around the origin, with an arbitrary radius $r>0$. We then have the simple parameterization for $C$: $$z(t)=r \exp{it};0 \leq t \leq 2 \pi, $$ and the integral is by definition $$\int_0^{2\pi} f(r \exp it)ir \exp it dt=\int_0^{\pi} f(r \exp it)ir \exp it dt+\int_\pi^{2\pi} f(r \exp it)ir \exp it dt $$

Using the substitution $t-\pi=\tau$ in the second integral gives $$\oint_C f(z)dz=\int_0^{\pi} f(r \exp it)ir \exp it dt+\int_0^\pi f(r \exp i(\tau+ \pi))ir \exp i(\tau+\pi)d\tau. $$
Simplifying the exponents, and using the fact that $f$ is even shows that the two sub-integrals cancel each other out.